# Create new column in dataframe based on certain conditions met in previous columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to create a new column in a dataframe based on if a certain value comes after another. Example my df looks like:
edit:(the values can contain (A,N,E,V))

```
Name  Jan Feb Mar April

John   N   N   E    E

Alex   E   E   E    E

Alice  E   E   E    N
```

I'd like to have a new column 'designation' that returns 1 if any person changed from an 'N' value from previous months to an 'E' and '0' if anything else.  Essentially this dataframe is from an excel file updated everymonth, so the latest month will appear in the last column.

I have a code

```
def func(u,x,y,z):
    if u =='N' and x== 'E':
        return 1
    elif x =='N' and y == 'E':
        return 1
     elif y =='N' and z == 'E':
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0
```

Essentially I want a code that doesn't need to be updated for every month and can just use the column indexes to return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Compare with the same dataframe shifted right. Since 'N' > 'E', casting to int will generate what you want

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Jan': list('NEE'), 'Feb': list('NEE'), 'Mar': 'E', 'April': list('EEN')})
>>> df
  Jan Feb Mar April
0   N   N   E     E
1   E   E   E     E
2   E   E   E     N
>>> (df < df.shift(1, axis=1)).astype(int)                                                              
   Jan  Feb  Mar  April
0    0    0    1      0
1    0    0    0      0
2    0    0    0      0
```

If you want to do the same for the last column only, just

```
(df.iloc[:, -1] < df.iloc[:, -2]).astype(int)
```

**UPD:** in case there are other letters, it should be:

```
(( df.shift(1, axis=1) == 'N') & (df == 'E')).astype(int)
```

or, for a single column:

```
((df.iloc[:, -2] == 'N') & (df.iloc[:, -1] == 'E')).astype(int)
```

Comment: How about if they contain other values (I forgot to include).  So it could be up to 4 letters actually.

Comment: explain how it should work and I'll update the answer

Comment: so lets say John could have instead (N,A,E,E) or (E,A,N,N) or (V,E,E,E) for months jan-april.  If at anypoint they were an N and shifted to an E they would have a value of 1.  As for as the casiting as int goes, if it were only two values of N or E that code would work just fine.  But let's say they had (V,E,E,E) then it would return 1 as well but it shouldn't because only looking for values that went from N->E. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: so, you only want to detect transition from N to E, is it correct?

Comment: correct, that is the only transition I'd like to detect